# Why is Msgbox/Inputbox getting so slow, and why turning Screenupdating to True can solve the problem?

Tags: excel, vba

As stated in the title, I already know the solution of the problem.

The thing is, I don't actually know why it works.

Sometimes when Msgbox/Inputbox pops up while macro is running, it gets very slow and the application might even stop responding.

However, after I insert a line of `Application.Screenupdating = True` before the Msgbox/Inputbox line, and `Application.Screenupdating = False` after it, the problem just gets solved.

Can someone give me some clues about why it works? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm going to guess that it suppresses messageboxes by turning it to `False`, so it's trying to show your messagebox and conflicting with the fact you have `ScreenUpdating` set as False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like BruceWayne commented input and message boxes require an input from the user, either an entry into the text box or clicking a button on the box. When you turn off screen updating the excel application will not show any changes on the screen. Because of that no user input can be entered and thus the code idles on the box until Excel freaks out and crashes.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.